# Program was killed (timeout reached) in Ada

Tags: exception, ada

I have an assignment in Ada to calculate VAT table; my code works good except when I will gave the following data:

**Given data:**

```
Firstprise: 1.0
lastprise: 2.0
step: 0.0
step: -0.1
step: 0.5
Procent: 50.0
```

It sends this error:

```
Program was killed (timeout reached).
```

but my code prints the following:

**Output data in my code:**

```
Pris utan moms  Moms  Pris med moms
1.00            0.50       1.50
1.50            0.75       2.25
2.00            1.00       3.00
```

Can any one help me please?

**My code is this:**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   startpris, stoppris, step : Float := -0.1;

   procent             : Float   := -0.1;
   priseftermoms, moms : Float;
   p                   : Float   := 100.0;
   I                   : Integer := 1;
   J                   : Float   := 0.0;
   x                   : Float   := -0.1;
   index               : Float   := 0.0;
   My_Exception : exception;

begin

   while startpris < J loop
      Put ("Första Pris: ");
      Get (startpris);

      if startpris < J then
         Put_Line (" Felaktigt värde!");

      end if;
   end loop;

   while stoppris < J or stoppris < startpris loop
      Put ("Sista Pris: ");
      Get (stoppris);
      --stoppris := Float'Value(Get_Line);
      if stoppris < J then
         Put_Line ("Felaktigt värde!");
      else
         if stoppris < startpris then
            Put_Line ("Felaktigt värde!");
         else
            Put ("");
         end if;
      end if;
   end loop;

   while step < J or step = J loop
      Put ("Steg: ");
      Get (step);
      --step  := Float'Value (Get_Line);
      if step < J then
         Put_Line (" Felaktigt värde!");
      else
         if step = J then
            Put_Line (" Felaktigt värde!");
         else
            Put ("");
         end if;
      end if;
   end loop;

   while procent < J or procent > p loop
      Put ("Momsprocent: ");
      Get (procent);
      if procent <= x then
         Put_Line (" Felaktigt värde!");
      end if;
      if procent > p then
         Put_Line (" Felaktigt värde!");
      end if;
   end loop;
   Put_Line ("");
   Put_Line ("=================== Momstabell =====================");
   Put_Line ("Pris utan moms        Moms           Pris med moms");

   while stoppris >= startpris - step / 3.0 loop

      moms          := (startpris * procent) / p;
      priseftermoms := moms + startpris;
      Put (startpris, Fore => 1, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
      Put ("                  ");
      Put (moms, Fore => 1, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
      Put ("                ");
      Put (priseftermoms, Fore => 1, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
      Put_Line ("");
      startpris := startpris + step;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to give an error? Is "timeout reached" something that your college’s marking system does if the program overruns? Your code as-is terminates with what look like correct results. Also, what’s with these these single-character meaningless variable names? What’s `J`? What’s `x`?

Comment: I have 10 test cases in my assigenment, all test case works as the teacher want, but the last test case didn't work. the result should be like  this:                                                         ' The submitted information provides the following output in the terminal => ERROR: Aborted due to very long execution time.
Program˽was˽killed˽ (timeout˽reached) . but I get numbers like above in my question.   J and x just a variabels to controll conditions in program för another test case. like negativ num.

Comment: You can eliminate the input of negative numbers by defining a subtype of float such as subtype valid_float is float range 0.0 .. float'last; This will allow you to simplify your program.

Comment: The system may timeout if the program takes too long time to run. This could happen if the program got stuck in a loop like if step < 0 or if stop < start. But you check for that so you must be ahead of the teacher :-).

Comment: @JimRogers, I don’t think this would simplify the program: Rand will have loops either way (and might have to catch an exception, too)

Comment: @Simon Wright, I must have missed something in the source listed above. Where is Rand employed?

Comment: @JimRogers, Rand is the person who posed the question! (they are a student, I’m guessing in Sweden)

Comment: @Rand, Thank you Simon. I apologize if I offended you Rand.